# Uptime of a Windows machine

Tags: windows, time

How can one find out 'real' uptime of a laptop?

By 'real' I mean the time since turning it on and resuming Windows from hybernation state.

Answer (score 5):

If just you want to know the time passed since the last boot, execute the bult-in command

```
 systeminfo
```

in a command line. Search for the "uptime" line.

Comment: Thanks for this great tip. The "System Boot Time" line gets me what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: i just noticed your "after hybernation" requirement - sorry, I don't think this will take that into account. You'll need to work this out from reading the event log. Uptime is time since last reboot. A hibernation is not a reboot. If "uptime" could be defined to take hibernation into account, I would expect it to mean all time spent awake since the last reboot (meaning minus all hibernation time), not just the time since last hibernation.

I use the free psinfo tool from sysinternals (now owned by microsoft, and still free)

```
C:\>psinfo

PsInfo v1.75 - Local and remote system information viewer
Copyright (C) 2001-2007 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

System information for \\LAPTOP:
Uptime:                    0 days 11 hours 28 minutes 27 seconds
Kernel version:            Windows 7 Ultimate, Multiprocessor Free
Product type:              Professional
Product version:           6.1
Service pack:              0
Kernel build number:       7100
...
```

Grab it from \live.sysinternals.com\tools\psinfo.exe (you can even run it directly from that unc link).

Comment: You can filter the output - "psinfo uptime" shows only that.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Windows Uptime** (free from MS) might help you with that, but I'm not sure if it will give you info about 'after' hybernation: [**http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232243**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232243)
2. I wonder if the default tools might help you (from cmd):

   **net statistics server** or
   **net statistics workstation**

Comment: 'net stats server' shows only timestamp of last system start

Comment: `net stats work`

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the other answers but they just aren't showing "uptime" or infos I need.

This one works for me on my Windows 7:

```
wevtutil qe System /q:"*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter']]]" /rd:true /c:1 /f:text > wake.txt
```

Run that command prompt and then look for a txt file on current directory

This uses the "Windows Event viewer" and the **> wake.txt** means it will save to a text file called **wake.txt**

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the other uptime command display a time that is not correct so I use this command to display the `LOGON TIME`

```
query USER
```

or shorter even:

```
quser
```

which prints something like:

```
C:\Users\eflorinescu>query  USER
 USERNAME                 SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>eflorinescu              console             2  Active    2+23:44  5/7/2018 8:25 AM
```

Comment: Isn't this solely **SESSION** uptime?

Comment: @ChrisMarisic If you are talking about the user session  yes it is the user session uptime